# How to access GCS bucket on the GCP while running on my local machine and also on the Google Cloud console form TensorFlow model?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-3.7

I am working on TensorFlow model on my local machine which run properly, now I want to deploy the model on Google Cloud Platform. But while the data is on the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

So my question are as follows:

1. How to access the Google Cloud Storage bucket to run my model on local machine and also on Google Cloud Platform console.
2. The Google Cloud Storage bucket's data are within multiple files, so how to import multiple files together using Python.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use gsutil to access Google Cloud Storage bucket, and copy file to vm's disk.

   gsutil cp gs://your-bucket/*
2. Use

```
from google.cloud import storage

# create storage client
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('your_credential.json')

# get bucket with name
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('yourbucket')

# get bucket data as blob
blob = bucket.get_blob('*')

# convert to string
json_data = blob.download_as_string()
```

Reference:

- [google.cloud.storage python api](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html)

Comment: Can you please answer to my this question also, it will be great help. "The GCP support python3.7 to deploy the tensorflow model and my model is base on python3.5 . Will i able to deploy tensorflow model. If no, then can anyone refer link where i will find differ in python3.6 and python3.7 syntax."

Comment: Hi you can use google deep learning image , which use python 3.5 
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/images

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I am working on the text data project, will this  above link will help me or work on my model.

Comment: You can just use this image with pre-install python 3.5 to create vm , but you don't have to use their library.